# SignalR OnDisconnected() not fired instantly for CORS client page

Tags: c#, iframe, signalr, cors, disconnect

I have a SignalR Chat application which is deployed on a server. The chatbox which users see should be renderd by the Chat Application in an iframe, on the targeted website.

I have problems with:

> Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)

If the Chat Application is up and running, and the connection is made with the server (for the admin side), and I close the tab, the OnDisconnected gets called instantly with stopCalled = true;

However, from the client page, which is a separate website in IIS, on port 81, instead of 80, if I connect and close the window, then OnDisconnected is called with a delay, and stopCalled is false;

Another weird thing is that if I render the client chat window from the Chat Application (i.e. entering the iframe's URL in a new tab, which renders the page on the same domain), **the OnDisconnected is called instantly**. So I suppose this is happening due to the client being either :

- rendered in an iframe
- rendered on a different domain
- both

Has anyone encountered this before ? 
I'm not sure what other details to give, I can give more if needed.

Using ASP.NET MVC 5, signalR 2.2.0, running on IIS 10

Thanks in advance,
Vlad

---- Update ----

I pulled everything out of the iframe and this is still happening.

Comment: Are you sure you do not have any Javascript event handler intercepting the unload of your page in the admin case and explicitly calling `stop()` on your connection? Did you try going in the SignalR code and put a breakpoint inside `stop()` to see if you get called there? Just wondering, the `stopCalled = true` bit is suspicious.

Comment: isn't stopCalled supposed to be true if the user closes the browser or the tab ? So the weird thing is it being false in the same scenario, on the client side

Comment: `stopCalled` is true when `stop()` has been called explicitly. Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24898839/720780